# TextInput won't scroll on focus (React Native)

Tags: react-native

I have a TextInput that is multiline that can bleed past the entire height of the screen. It takes up the whole screen. Whenever there is text that takes up the whole screen, I can't scroll down or up. Whenever I tap to scroll down or up, it focuses on the text input where I tapped.

The scrolling up or down feature of the ScrollView it is inside of no longer works.

How can I keep a scrolling feature when the TextInput takes up the whole screen?

Here's my code:

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView 
    style={styles.screen}
    behavior={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "padding" : "height"}
>
    <View style={styles.body}>
        <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.scrollViewCont} keyboardShouldPersistTaps={'always'}>
            <TextInput 
                style={styles.noteTitle}
                placeholder={'Note Title'}
                value={noteTitle}
                onChangeText={setNoteTitle}
                multiline={true}
            />
            <TextInput 
                style={styles.noteText}
                placeholder={'Note Text'}
                value={noteText}
                onChangeText={setNoteText}
                multiline={true}
            />
        </ScrollView>
    </View>
    {showFooter ? <GlobalFooter AppState={AppState} navigation={navigation} /> : null}
</KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

Comment: Can You share the code beacuse there must be some modification required in current code or may be some bug ?? Also try this pointerEvents="none" .

Comment: @Jagroop I just added my code.

Comment: I think you should wrap like this  <KeyboardAvoidingView> <ScrollView> <View> ... </View> </ScrollView> </KeyboardAvoidingView> .

Comment: I think you find your answer .As you commented below .

Answer (score 0):

I had to give the TextInput a set height. Once I gave the TextInput a height, it became scrollable even when I was focused on it.